# android value with string array item in resources

Tags: java, android, resources

So I have a string-array

```
<string-array name="string_array">
   <item>A</item>
   <item>B</item>
   <item>C</item>
</string-array>
```

and I would like to assign values to those strings such as

```
<string-array name="string_array">
   <item value="1">A</item>
   <item value="2">B</item>
   <item value="3">C</item>
</string-array>
```

is there any easy way to do this? I could just store it in an xml file and read it in at runtime but I thought somebody might have an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, no, there isn't. But what I do is I use `A,1`, `B,2`  ... as `string-array`. And at runtime I just loop through array and build a map like `String[] keyValue = value.split(",");` and `map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);`

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that the type of array you are looking for even exists. Arrays are to be accessed through index not key value pairs. For your purpose I think that only string tag is sufficient because you can access an item by its name just like you wanted.